# Preg Match Between Curly Braces - preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Example Subject: {this}{is}a{my} {example}{{subject}}
To return:

```
array(
[1] => 'this' 
[2] => 'is' 
[3] => 'my'
[4] => 'example'
[5] => 'subject'
```

This is common in php templating engines 
cite smarty and twig
http://www.smarty.net/
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: So where's your regular expression?

Comment: I dont know what you are asking

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the following code:

```
$str = '{this}{is}a{my} {example}{{subject}}';

if(preg_match_all('/{+(.*?)}/', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(4) "this"
  [1] =>
  string(2) "is"
  [2] =>
  string(2) "my"
  [3] =>
  string(7) "example"
  [4] =>
  string(7) "subject"
}
```

Comment: Perfection thank you sir. For anyone interested the basic context of this is the ability to for instance call a particular variable to your template from administration etc without interfering directly with core code. I will add additional links to other questions that relate to creating your own template solutions via php preg_match. Thanks to hek2mgl for the answer. Cheers - gitscripts.com

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte note that `<Casimir><et><Hippolyte>` won't work as well but this is not in question. A regex is for a particular usage. You've posted a different usage so don't expect my regex to work for a different usage.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte What means `Like you prefer` ??