# Preg Match only digits Between Curly Braces - preg_match

Tags: find, match, str-replace, digits, curly-braces

Related to [Preg Match Between Curly Braces - preg_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247482/preg-match-between-curly-braces-preg-match/46913562)

What if my string is: this an example with {2} words and {7} numbers

And I want to return:

```
array(
[1] => 2
[2] => 7
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where the linked question used `.` to match *any* character, you can use `\d` to match any digit character (0-9):

```
$str = 'this an example with {2} words and {7} numbers';

if(preg_match_all('/{+(\d*?)}/', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "7"
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/MmXp6E/1